# Searching columns and seeing if blank or not

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So i would like to search a ToolID and DateIN columns and see if DateIN is blank and ToolID is NOT blank which if this is true it should put the toolID into a variable.. is this possible.

so the end goal of this to send a email with all the ToolID's that don't have a DateIN...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSkSv.png)

I have tried a IF statement but i didnt come right with it completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of "Tool ID" column when "Tool ID" column has a value and "Date In" column is empty.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

If you can give the column numbers of "Tool ID" and "Date In", how about the following sample script?

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const toolIdCol = 1; // 1 is column "A". Please set the column number of "Tool ID" column.
  const dateInCol = 5; // 5 is column "E". Please set the column number of "Date In" column.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const [, ...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const res = values.filter(r => r[toolIdCol - 1] && !r[dateInCol - 1]).map(r => r[toolIdCol - 1]);
  if (res.length == 0) {
    console.log("No values.");
    return;
  }
  console.log(res); // You can see the result values in the log.
}
```

If the order of the header is sometimes changed and you cannot give the column numbers of "Tool ID" and "Date In", how about the following sample script?

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const [headers, ...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const obj = values.map(r => headers.reduce((o, h, i) => (o[h.toLowerCase()] = r[i], o), {}));
  const res = obj.filter(o => o["tool id"] && !o["date in"]).map(o => o["tool id"]);
  if (res.length == 0) {
    console.log("No values.");
    return;
  }
  console.log(res); // You can see the result values in the log.
}
```

- Both scripts return the values of "Tool ID" are retrieved when "Tool ID" column has a value and "Date In" column is empty.

Comment: Is there a way i can contact you quickly now so that you can maybe help me quickly... Sorry im very new to this apps scripts... it seems easy but i just dont know the syntax for apps scripts

Comment: @Keanan Dunn Thank you for replying. About `Is there a way i can contact you quickly now so that you can maybe help me quickly`, I cannot do it. I apologize for this. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot understand the issue of my answer for your question. Can I ask you about the detail of it? I would like to confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I have to apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Email toolId's missing and date:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Tools");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 5).getValues();
  const f = vs.map(([a,,,,e]) => (a && !e) ? a : "").filter(e => e).flat();
  //GmailApp.sendEmail("rec","Subject",f.join(","))
  Logger.log(f.join(","));
}
```